Android studio - rerun failed tests doesn't work
I run my tests with "gradle check" - everything works fine.
When I click button "Rerun failed tests" I get:
"Test event were not received"
Executing tasks: [check, --tests, com.something.something.PlatformConfigTest.getProductionServerUrl] in project ...
...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Problem configuring task :something:check from command line.


Unknown command-line option '--tests'.

I tried different gradle versions, updated IDE to ladybug but nothing helps

Hi, can you provide more details so I can identify the exact issue during unit testing?
